# An API level of 32 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier

Tags: android

> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"An API level of 32 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
> An API level of 32 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier

Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.common.repository.GradleVersion.tryParseAndroidGradlePluginVersion(GradleVersion.java:547)
at com.android.build.attribution.BuildAttributionManagerImpl.onBuildSuccess(BuildAttributionManagerImpl.kt:84)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl$TaskImpl.lambda$invokeGradleTasks$2(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:390)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:130)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:161)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:130)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:181)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl$TaskImpl.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:483)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleTasksExecutorImpl$TaskImpl.run(GradleTasksExecutorImpl.java:224)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:450)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:117)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:510)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:243)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:183)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:243)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: Try this thread -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312198/an-api-level-of-31-is-not-supported-by-this-compiler-please-use-an-api-level-of

Answer (score -1):

1. change  [image]
2. to [image]
3. add below code in buile.gradle(:app) file

{android
......

compileSdkVersion 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xyz"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

}