# Installation did not succeed in Android version 12 - API 31 and above

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-version

I tried to install my application in an Android version 12. I added the `android:exported` for each activity, receiver and filters. This error occurs

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\Code\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session 366841949 with command package install-commit 366841949. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl366841949.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #392): androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

The merged manifist displays these errors

```
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. myapp.app main manifest (this file), line 26
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. muapp.app main manifest (this file), line 33
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. myapp.app main manifest (this file), line 40
```

This is the test AndroidManifest.XML file that causes the errors

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="androidx.test.core" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

These are the test dependencies I'm using

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0')
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.4.0')
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:rules:1.4.0')
```

The problem occurs in the test package and its auto generated. How to fix it?

I tried multiple solutions to fix the problem but nothing seems to fix it.

These are some solutions I looked into but didn't work for me.

- [Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333565/targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-an-explicit-value-for-android)
- 
- [An API level of 31 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312198/an-api-level-of-31-is-not-supported-by-this-compiler-please-use-an-api-level-of)

Comment: "The problem occurs in the test package" -- what exactly do you mean by this? Beyond that, I recommend posting your manifest, at least the `<activity>` entry for `com.example.myapp.authactivity.Splash`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I included the test manifest file that causes the error.
This activity `androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity` is in the test package where I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was fixed by changing this dependency version `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing`

from version 1.3.5

`debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.5'`

to version 1.4.0

`debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.0'`

This answer helped me fix the error https://stackoverflow.com/a/71605255/9770844

Comment: Why are you using `debugImplementation`, rather than a test-specific directive (`testImplementation` for unit tests, `androidTestImplementation` for instrumented tests)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not sure why the previous developer used it, but I assume they had a debug compiler.
But for my knowledge that android documentation suggests it 
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test#groovy